# Do negative numbers consume more memory?

Tags: java, memory, bit

So I have this test program that checks the binary value of an integer one is positive and another is negative.

```
int i = 100;
int i2 = -100;

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i2));
```

**result:**

```
1100100
11111111111111111111111110011100
```

As you could see negative number has more bits than the positive number, does this mean that the negative number consumes more memory than positive number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is how it gets represented internally, with positive number it has same number of bit to represent an int value

it is just avoiding leading zeros

Answer (score 9):

No, both are 32 bit quantities - the width of an integer is fixed on a given platform. It's "shorter" because it's truncating all the leading 0's.

You might want to do some reading on integer representation, specifically two's complement representation.

Answer (score 3):

No. The numbers consume the same number of bits internally, when you called `toBinaryString()` it removed the leading zeros. Per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29),

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.

Finally, you could check [Integer.SIZE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE),

```
System.out.println(Integer.SIZE);
```

Output is

```
32
```

Because Java `int` is 32-bits.

Answer (score 3):

No it wont. The maximum lower and upper limit for the integer (int) in Java is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Remember that 'int' consumes 4 Bytes (32 Bits).

Lets put this in Binary now..It is:

```
1111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 
 7 bits  8 bits   8 bits   8 bits
```

In total it is 31 bits (the first column has only 7 bits). The remaining one bit is the Sign bit - The sign bit indicates the sign. If set(ie. 1), it is negative, if not - positive.

So for positive number (max) it would be

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

and for negative it would be

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

So the sizes are going to be the same.

Languages like C,C++ and C# - support unsigned integers (uint) which is also 32 bits and have a range of 0 to 4,294,967,295. It discards the sign bit and counts it in.